# Magento - Sort Items on Package Slip by SKU

Tags: php, arrays, magento, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to sort the items on a package slip by SKU. I've got at custom package slip module with this function that returns the items:

```
class Devweb_Packslip_Model_Order_Shipment extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment
{
    public function setOrder(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
    {
        parent::setOrder($order);

        $this->_items = array();
        $items = $order->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $shipmentItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_item');
            $shipmentItem->setShipment($this);
            $shipmentItem->setProductId($item->getProductId());
            $shipmentItem->setOrderItem($item);
            $shipmentItem->setQty($item->getQtyToShip());
            $shipmentItem->setSku($item->getSku());
            $skuArray[] = $shipmentItem->getSku();
            if (!$shipmentItem->getName()) {
                $shipmentItem->setName($item->getName());
            }
            $this->_items[] = $shipmentItem;
        }

    }
}
```

So i basically need to sort $items og $this->_items
I've search around and I'm not certain how I do it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you swap the line
`$items = $order->getAllItems();`

with the code `$items = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()->setOrderFilter($order)->setOrder('sku','asc');` then that should work

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. That didn't solve it. I tried to output the SKU in the log within the foreach loop. The output still returns the same sorting.

Comment: I've tested that code and there's no reason why it shouldn't work. What version of magento are you using?

Comment: Hmm. I'm using Magento 1.9.1